# Rails 4 route constraints with query string or numbers only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to implement these two routes with constraints:

```
get "products/:id", to: "products#show", constraints: { id: /\d/ }
get "products/:name", to: "products#search", constraints: { name: /[a-zA-Z]/ }
```

The first route should trigger with an URL like `localhost:3000/products/3` and the last one should trigger with `localhost:3000/products/?name=juice`.

Doesn't work, I googled a lot about this problem but I seem to find solutions for the second or third version of Ruby on Rails, and most of them are deprecated now.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: As written, your second route would respond to something like: `localhost:3000/products/juice`. Is that what you are after?

Comment: It does respond with `localhost:3000/products/juice`, problem is that I have to use query string in order to get the name parameter, not the id parameter. I'm looking for a way that routes can respond depending if there's a number or a name in the URL.

Comment: Threre's no need to use a query string to get the value of `name`. I'll expand in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the routes as-is if you like the look of the resulting URLs. No need for a query string.

In your controller, you'd have something along these lines:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # do stuff
end

def search
  # I'm assuming your Product model has a `name` attribute
  @product = Product.find_by(name: params[:name])
  # do stuff
end
```

You probably want some error checking on `find_by` returning nil because `:name` did not match anything, but that's basically it.

Your routes.rb would have your original route definition:

```
get "products/:id", to: "products#show", constraints: { id: /[[:digit]]/ }
get "products/:name", to: "products#search", constraints: { name: /[[:alpha:]]/ }
```

Your application should respond to both:

- localhost:3000/products/3
- localhost:3000/products/juice

Comment: Interesting... So in the `routes.rb` file it should have: `get "products/:name", to: "products#search"` and `get "products/:id", to: "products#show"`, right?

Comment: It returns this error `Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /^[a-zA-Z]/` but according to @PJSCopeland answer I removed the anchor and added a plus sign at the final of the regex. Works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that, remove the '^'. I stuffed up in a prior edit.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know what the query string and url.
`localhost:3000/products/3` this is url and the three is symbol :id when use question mark `localhost:3000/products/3?name=juice`, name=juice is query string.

So `get "products/:name", to: "products#search", constraints: { name: /[a-zA-Z]/ }` you should replace below

```
get "products/:id?name=:name", to: "products#search", constraints: { id: /\d/,
                                                                name: /[a-zA-Z]/ }
```

example: localhost:3000/products/3?name=xxxxx

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either.  I'm looking for a way that routes can respond depending if there's a number or a name in the URL, example, if there's a number as a parameter, then execute the show action using that number as id, else, execute the search action using the name parameter passed in the query string. Anyway, I appreciate your response.

Comment: `get "/products?name=:name", to: "products#search", constraints: { name: /[a-zA-Z]/ }`.

Because  `get "products/:id"` and `get "products/:name"` are same it.
You should to design specify search url to handle.

Comment: You don't specify parameters after the `?` in the routes. The different constraints for the parameters should tell them which one to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling the regex matching might be a little different in routes - I think it anchors to the start and end of the parameter every time.

With that in mind, your regexes are matching a single character each. Try `id: /\d+/` and `name: /.*\D.*/` instead.

Comment: An old app I worked on had `[a-zA-Z.0-9_\-]` instead of simply `.` - you might have to use that.

Comment: From the routing guide: ":constraints takes regular expressions with the restriction that regexp anchors can't be used" and "However, note that you don't need to use anchors because all routes are anchored at the start.". They are not anchored at the end, just the start.

Comment: Ah, right. The last time I had to use these was a couple of years ago, so I must have forgotten.

Comment: Then again, Cat said it worked just by putting the `+` on the end, which surely wouldn't have made the difference if it didn't anchor to the end as well...?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier and more Railsy just to specify a different route:

```
get "products/:id",          to: "products#show"
get "products/search/:name", to: "products#search"
```

Or, just have your `products#index` action handle `params[:q]` as the search string, that's quite common too. Then your URL would be `www.example.com/products?q=juice`.